# Select order with row counter not working as expected

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My rank order is not correct, where in this query is the order not matching the rank?

```
SELECT @r := @r+1 as rank, 
        z.* 
 FROM(
         SELECT 
             u.user_id,
             u.score,
             c.username
             FROM `e_highscores` u
     
             JOIN (
                 SELECT  cc.user_id, cc.username
                 FROM e_users as cc
                 ) as c
                 ON  u.user_id = c.user_id
     ORDER BY  u.score DESC
 )z, 
 (SELECT @r:=0)y;
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

---

---

**Switching the order by to:**

```
        SELECT @r := @r+1 as rank, 
        z.* 
 FROM(
         SELECT 
             u.user_id,
             u.score,
             c.username
             FROM `e_highscores` u
     
             JOIN (
                 SELECT  cc.user_id, cc.username
                 FROM e_users as cc
                 ) as c
                ON  u.user_id = c.user_id
       
 )z, 
 (SELECT @r:=0)y
  ORDER BY  z.score DESC
```

---

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Please share the example data and create table queries. BTW, how about try to add order by score in the end of your query?

Comment: See updated question, btw I cannot share the table data they are very simple tables being joined on user_id, nothing outside the norm for a table with ids and values

Comment: I did some test, it seems that you sql could run correctly. However all result is too long to  show in comment. I have to post them as an answer.Please see them in answer part and I will follow according your updates.

Answer (score 2):

I create a table in my sandbox (mysql 5.7.31), and it seems that your query could get correct result:

```
CREATE TABLE `e_highscores` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `e_users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into `e_highscores` (user_id, score) values (2, 200), (15, 300), (11,121);
insert into `e_users` (user_id, username) values (2, 'Pie'), (15, 'Adam'), (11, 'Hershey');

SELECT @r := @r+1 as urank,
    z.*
FROM(
 SELECT
     u.user_id,
     u.score,
     c.username
     FROM `e_highscores` u

     JOIN e_users as c
     ON  u.user_id = c.user_id

) z,
(SELECT @r:=0) y
ORDER BY  z.score DESC;
```

The result is:

```
1   15  300 Adam
2   2   200 Pie
3   11  121 Hershey
```

I guess your issue may be caused by 'rank' keyword in mysql??
Could you let me know your mysql version, please?

---

**mariadb is different with mysql when using user defined variable with `order by` together.**

> Beware order of evaluation of rows when sorting. It would appear (at
> least as far as I've tested it) that when statements of the form:
>
> SELECT @var:= FROM...
>
> are executed, @var will always correspond to the value in the last row
> returned, as you might expect.
>
> But if you do something like:
>
> SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(@var:=Name,'unknown') FROM Customers ORDER BY
>  LIMIT 10
>
> **The statement containing the variable assignment will be executed**
> ***before* the order-by**. In this case, the value left in @var at the end might not even correspond to any of the rows returned!

Please refer to [mariadb offical doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-variables/) for more details.

To generate correct result, please use the following query:

```
select 
  urank, t.user_id, t.score, c.username 
from (
  select 
    @row := @row + 1 as urank, 
    u.user_id, 
    u.score 
  from e_highscores u 
  order by score desc
) t join e_users as c on t.user_id = c.user_id 
order by score desc;
```

Comment: Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.41-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 - Debian 9.9

Comment: Hmm this did not fix the rank. It still shows as screenshot #2 in the original post

Comment: @Petro, please see if my updates are what you want.